# Prevent shiny from updating elements of plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am trying to keep the color scale and size scale of my plot constant, regardless of which points are actually displayed.

In `ggplot`, I could set these constant using arguments like `scale_color_gradient(limits=c(0,1))`. However, I cannot find a parallel function in `plot_ly` and for other reasons, I cannot use `ggplotly()` here.

I believe this can also be done with `eventReactive()` but I'm having trouble understanding how to use it.

Here is a minimal example, where the plot color and size keep changing.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

df <- as.data.frame(list("UserID"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                          "Category"=c('A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B'),
                          "Rate"=c(2,3,5,6,8,6,7,1),
                          "x"=c(1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8),
                          "y"=c(1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8)
                    ))

ui <- (fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("userInput","Select User", sort(unique(df$UserID)),
                  selected=1),
      checkboxGroupInput("CategoryInput", "Select Category", sort(unique(df$Category)),
                         selected=c('A','B'))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("mainPlot")#,
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # filter for both user and category
  filteredFull <- reactive({
      df %>% 
        filter(
          UserID == input$userInput,
          Category %in% input$CategoryInput
        )
  })

  output$mainPlot <- renderPlotly({
        plot_ly(data=filteredFull(), x=x, y=y,
                       color=Rate, size=Rate,
                       mode='markers')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is it possible to update only which points are displayed, without updating the scale/range of the color/size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plotly has those colorscale limits as well. They are nested under the marker attribute. You can set the color scales maximum and minimum values (numeric values) to leave the scale constant regardless which points are actually displayed.

I just added `marker = list(cmin = 1, cmax = 8)` to the `plot_ly` command. So you would have to scan your `df` to determine which are your maximum and minimum values.

Code below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

df <- as.data.frame(list(
  "UserID" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
  "Category" = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
  "Rate" = c(2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 6, 7, 1),
  "x" = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8),
  "y" = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8)
))

ui <- (fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("userInput","Select User", sort(unique(df$UserID)), selected=1),
      checkboxGroupInput("CategoryInput", "Select Category", sort(unique(df$Category)), selected=c('A','B'))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("mainPlot"),
      plotlyOutput("mainPlotFixedSize")
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # filter for both user and category
  filteredFull <- reactive({
      df %>% 
        filter(
          UserID == input$userInput,
          Category %in% input$CategoryInput
        )
  })

  output$mainPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(data=filteredFull(), x=x, y=y,
      color=Rate, size=Rate,
      mode='markers', marker = list(cmin = 1, cmax = 8))
  })

  output$mainPlotFixedSize <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(data=filteredFull(), x=x, y=y,
      color=Rate, mode='markers', 
      marker = list(sizemode = "area", size = Rate*3400, cmin = 1, cmax = 8))
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is great for the color scale! Thank you! What about for the size? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: A bit late, but I edited my answer to include the size. Controlling the size is much more difficult. It's actually easy, but you have to do all size adjustments by hand. I chose the Rate factor (min. 3400 px area) by experimenting.

Comment: @Adam_G Could you check if the updated answer is working for you?